# How to select entities by calling a stored procedure with Spring Data

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have a MySQL stored procedure that contains the following select:

```
select * from users;
```

How to use the `@Procedure` annotation in a `JpaRepository` so that I can get the results? Something like:

```
public UserRepository extenda JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    @Procedure('get_users')
    List<User> getUsers();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say this is your procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_users()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM USERS;
END
```

You define a `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery`:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name="getUsers", 
    procedureName="get_users", 
    resultClass=User.class, parameters={
        @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="data", name="data", direction=Direction.OUT_CURSOR)
    }
)
@Entity
public class User {
    ...
}
```

And then you can call your procedure like this:

```
public UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    @Procedure('User.getUsers')
    List<User> getUsers();
}
```

You can also check this using your EntityManager like this:

```
Query query = entitymanager.createNamedQuery("getUsers");
List users = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Can't I do something similar in the Repository?

Comment: It will definitely work. I was searching for a way to put it in the repository because everything I have related to database transactions is there

Comment: Hello again, I tried the solution you proposed and I keep encountering different issues. I tried the last 8 hours to find why this is not working and I hope you may help me. I opened another topic here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097667/illegalargumentexception-type-cannot-be-null

Comment: As usual, your solution doesn't work at all