# IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am confronting with an issue and it seems that many people encountered it and probably couldn't solve it.

I have the following MYSQL stored procedure. This is just a sample to see if everything works fine, then I would've start adding parameters like `inactive`.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_resource_types`()
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM resource_types
    WHERE inactive = 0;
END
```

The entity which maps the `resource_types` table and the named stored procedure query.

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name="getResourceTypes",
        procedureName="get_resource_types",
        resultClasses = ResourceType.class,
        parameters = {}
)
@Entity
@Table(name = "resource_types")
public class ResourceType {
    ... fields with annotations used for validation + getters and setters ...
}
```

And here is my `JpaRepository` from which I make the call to the stored procedure

```
@Repository
public interface ResourceTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<ResourceType, Long> {
    @Procedure("ResourceType.getResourceTypes")
    List<ResourceType> getResourceTypes();

}
```

The `getAll()` method which resides in a `@Service`

```
public List<ResourceType> getAll(){
    final List<ResourceType> resourceTypes = resourceTypeRepository.getResourceTypes();
    return resourceTypes;
}
```

When I try to run this I get the following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Type cannot be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:144)
    at com.test.ihbs.controller.ResourceTypeControllerTest.test_getAll(ResourceTypeControllerTest.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Type cannot be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:381)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:223)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.getResourceTypes(Unknown Source)
    at com.ihbs.service.ResourceTypeService.getAll(ResourceTypeService.java:34)
    at com.ihbs.controller.ResourceTypeController.getAllResourceTypes(ResourceTypeController.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.setHibernateType(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.<init>(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.<init>(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.<init>(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.PositionalParameterRegistration.<init>(PositionalParameterRegistration.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.registerParameter(ProcedureCallImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.registerStoredProcedureParameter(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:128)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.newAdhocStoredProcedureQuery(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:147)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.createStoredProcedure(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:110)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.createQuery(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:58)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ProcedureExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:295)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:395)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:373)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:486)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 80 more
```

Any ideas why is this happening and how to fix it?

The documentation for `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` says:

> Exception thrown on incorrect usage of the API, such as failing to
>   "compile" a query object that needed compilation before execution.
>   This represents a problem in our Java data access framework, not the
>   underlying data access infrastructure.

**UPDATE 1**

If I change the repository into the following code, it will work, which means there are issues with name procedure query. I still need to make the stored procedure way to work.

```
@Repository
public interface ResourceTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<ResourceType, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT rt FROM ResourceType rt WHERE rt.inactive = 0")
    List<ResourceType> getResourceTypes();

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I am not using EclipseLink (or at least I don't know about his existence)

**UPDATE 3**

I could not found the cause of this problem even if I went through the code, debugging. But I found something that may help in finding the issue.

I found this piece of code in `org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java` and if you may notice that on the last line there is a call to a function where it gets the total number of parameters and adds an extra one. Here may be the problem, the extra parameter. Still, this may not be the issue because I suppose it can follow another path under different circumstances.

```
/**
 * Extracts the output value from the given {@link StoredProcedureQuery}.
 * 
 * @param storedProcedureQuery must not be {@literal null}.
 * @return
 */
Object extractOutputValue(StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery) {

    Assert.notNull(storedProcedureQuery, "StoredProcedureQuery must not be null!");

    if (!procedureAttributes.hasReturnValue()) {
        return null;
    }

    if (StringUtils.hasText(procedureAttributes.getOutputParameterName())) {
        return storedProcedureQuery.getOutputParameterValue(procedureAttributes.getOutputParameterName());
    }

    return storedProcedureQuery.getOutputParameterValue(getQueryMethod().getParameters().getNumberOfParameters() + 1);
}
```

Comment: likely the question is why is Spring "StoredProcedureJpaQuery.newAdhocStoredProcedureQuery" calling "StoredProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter" if there are no parameters? Perhaps you should delve through Spring source code and debug it?

Comment: Have you tried removing the (optional) `parameters` in the `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` definition?

Comment: Yes, I tried to remove them and I have the same result. Is it required to have a parameter? I have a feeling that the system expects a parameter like an `OUT` or `REF_CURSOR`.

Comment: it is obviously NOT required to have a parameter, hence why the default is NOT to have parameters in that annotation. As already said, resolve why Spring is calling that method and you have your answer. I've used stored procedures in DataNucleus and I'm sure I had at least one with no parameter

Comment: @NeilStockton I updated my issue. Please take a look. This may be relevant. I couldn't find the real problem.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: No, I haven't. After encountering this issue and trying to find a solution for about one week I decided to go for pure JDBC.

Comment: Damn, I have a Stored procedure in an Oracle DB that takes in one IN parameter (Long) and outputs two OUT parameters (both user-defined custom types) and I tried mapping to the Entity for the StoredProc in my Java just like you and i 'm getting the same error!! If I get a solution I will update here.

Answer (score 4):

Spring Data JPA as of 1.11.1 does not support SPs returning result sets. I filed [a corresponding defect](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1092) with Spring Data.

The solution is to descend an API level and just use JPA. Here is a generic class that I wrote that works with MS SQL SPs.

```
import com.google.common.base.Strings;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.ParameterMode;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class StoredProcRepository {

  //region Injected beans (via a RequiredArgsConstructor)
  private final EntityManager em;
  //endregion 

  /**
   * Calls a stored procedure via JPA and retrieves a single implicit result set (in DBs that
   * support them e.g. MS SQL or MySQL). The call is not dependent on a DB dialect. Be
   * aware that large result sets should be paginated and not entirely read to memory. Recreates
   * StoredProcedureQuery instance and its parameters on each call.
   * To execute MS SQL SPs performing multiple queries, SET NOCOUNT ON.
   *
   * @param procedureName stored procedure name, optionally qualified per DB syntax
   * @param resultClass converts (maps) each result set row into instances of resultClass via JPA
   * @param spArgs stored procedure arguments, supplied positionally (optional SP arguments at the
   * end of the list could be omitted)
   * @param <T> class of row instances converted per JPA
   * @return the entire result set
   */
  public <T> List<T> queryViaStoredProc(String procedureName, Class<T> resultClass,
      Object... spArgs) {
    StoredProcedureQuery spq = em.createStoredProcedureQuery(procedureName, resultClass);
    int pos = 0;
    for (Object arg : spArgs) {
      spq.registerStoredProcedureParameter(++pos, arg.getClass(), ParameterMode.IN);
      spq.setParameter(pos, arg);
    }
    return spq.getResultList();
  }

  /**
   * Calls a stored procedure via JPA and retrieves only the top row of a single implicit result
   * set (in DBs that support them e.g. MS SQL or MySQL).
   * Assumes that result set has at least one row.
   * The call is not dependent on a DB dialect.
   * Be aware that large result sets should be paginated and not entirely read to memory.
   * Recreates StoredProcedureQuery instance and its parameters on each call.
   * To execute MS SQL SPs performing multiple queries, SET NOCOUNT ON.
   *
   * @param procedureName stored procedure name, optionally qualified per DB syntax
   * @param resultClass converts (maps) each result set row into instances of resultClass via JPA
   * @param spArgs stored procedure arguments, supplied positionally (optional SP arguments at the
   * end of the list could be omitted)
   * @param <T> class of row instances converted per JPA
   * @return the entire result set
   */
  public <T> T queryTopRowViaStoredProc(String procedureName, Class<T> resultClass,
      Object... spArgs) {
    return queryViaStoredProc(procedureName, resultClass, spArgs).get(0);
  }
}
```

For MS SQL SPs, the additional requirement is to have `SET NOCOUNT ON` for all SPs executing more than one query. This could be set in one of at least three ways:

1. In a generic Java wrapper using JPA (see code below). This approach works only with jTDS JDBC driver. [A corresponding issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/313) has been filed with MS JDBC driver project.
2. In the beginning of each SP.
3. [Globally in your database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statements-transact-sql).

Her is code for #1: corresponding methods for the same `StoredProcRepository` class.

```
  /**
   * Calls an MS SQL stored procedure via JPA and retrieves a single implicit result set.
   * Protects against lack of SET NOCOUNT in stored procedures.
   * This works with jTDS JDBC driver, but not with MS JDBC driver.
   * Be aware that large result sets should be paginated and not entirely read to memory.
   *
   * @param procedureName stored procedure name, optionally qualified per DB syntax
   * @param resultClass converts (maps) each result set row into instances of resultClass via JPA
   * @param spArgs stored procedure arguments, supplied positionally (optional SP arguments at the
   * end of the list could be omitted)
   * @param <T> class of row instances converted per JPA
   * @return the entire result set
   */
  public <T> List<T> queryViaMsSqlStoredProc(String procedureName, Class<T> resultClass,
      Object... spArgs) {
    String spBindParams = (spArgs.length == 0) ? "" : "?" + Strings.repeat(",?", spArgs.length - 1);

    // The following works with jTDS driver, but not with MS driver
    String spQuery = String.format("EXEC %s %s", procedureName, spBindParams);

    // The following works with jTDS driver, but not with MS driver
    /*
    String spQuery = String.format("{call %s(%s)}", procedureName, spBindParams);
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SET NOCOUNT ON; " + spQuery, resultClass)
        .setHint("org.hibernate.readOnly", true);
    */

    Query q = em.createNativeQuery(spQuery, resultClass);
    int pos = 0;
    for (Object arg : spArgs) {
      q.setParameter(++pos, arg);
    }
    return q.getResultList();
  }    

  /**
   * Calls an MS SQL stored procedure via JPA and retrieves only the top row of a single implicit
   * result set.
   * Assumes that result set has at least one row.
   * The call sets the "NOCOUNT ON" MS SQL batch option.
   * Be aware that large result sets should be paginated and not entirely read to memory.
   *
   * @param procedureName stored procedure name, optionally qualified per DB syntax
   * @param resultClass converts (maps) each result set row into instances of resultClass via JPA
   * @param spArgs stored procedure arguments, supplied positionally (optional SP arguments at the
   * end of the list could be omitted)
   * @param <T> class of row instances converted per JPA
   * @return the entire result set
   */
  public <T> T queryTopRowViaMsSqlStoredProc(String procedureName, Class<T> resultClass,
      Object... spArgs) {
    return queryViaMsSqlStoredProc(procedureName, resultClass, spArgs).get(0);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem seems to be while mapping your results (resulting entity can't be typed).

Try changing:

```
@Procedure("ResourceType.getResourceTypes")
List<ResourceType> getResourceTypes();
```

to

```
@Procedure("ResourceType.getResourceTypes")
Object[] getResourceTypes();
```

and remove the resultClasses in your NamedStoredProcedureQuery.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with MS SQL SP. Switching to List<Object[]> and no resultClasses hasn't solved this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these two ways

1. Change below lines

   @Procedure("ResourceType.getResourceTypes")
   List getResourceTypes();

like this

```
List<ResourceType> getResourceTypes();  // because as per JPA if your method name matches with the @NamedStoredProcedure -> name then no need to mention @Procedure annotation.
```

2. If you want to use @Procedure annotation then change the below lines

   @Procedure("ResourceType.getResourceTypes")
   List getResourceTypes();

like this

```
@Procedure(name="getResourceTypes")
List<ResourceType> getResourceTypes();
```

Comment: I faced with same issue and get just crazy. Just needed to add "name=" in @Procedure annotation. A subtle difference that made me throw away a couple of hours...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error which got resolved by changing ParameterMode.OUT to
ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR.
I had written this mistakenly.

`query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(12, ResultSet.class, ParameterMode.OUT);`

`query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(12, ResultSet.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Type cannot be null`

In my case, I have a Postgres function with an array of text as a parameter. Tried a bunch of solution but nothing works.

In the end I decided to use a workaround and changed the function parameter from array of text to just text and convert it to array.

`CREATE FUNCTION fn_funcName(IN arrAsString TEXT)`

Inside the function convert text to array using STRING_TO_ARRAY

`arr := STRING_TO_ARRAY(arrAsString, ',');`

Also, might actually worth noting when using the function. Converting a list to array using toString() may not work because of the brackets []. I use `String.join(",", listOfText);` instead of listOfText.toString()