# IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null (in JAVA)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm facing the exact issue as described in this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097667/illegalargumentexception-type-cannot-be-null) which hasn't been answered. I've tried the suggestions given in the comment section, nothing works.

I've searched online for the answers and found no luck.

My Procedure looks like this.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS userdb.new_test;
CREATE PROCEDURE userdb.new_test (IN arg varchar(255))
BEGIN   
  select * FROM message 
END;
```

and from this [link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-how-to-solve-illegal-argument-exception/) I got to know

> This exception indicates that a method is called with incorrect input arguments. Then, the only thing you must do is correct the values of the input parameters. In order to achieve that, follow the call stack found in the stack trace and check which method produced the invalid argument.

does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

That's most probably because of the non-default value parameter in your procedure `IN arg varchar(255)` and if not wrong you are probably calling the procedure without passing any parameter. You need to call like

```
call userdb.new_test 'some value'
```

`MySQL` doesn't support parameter default value likewise in `SQL Server` and so you can't say `IN arg varchar(255) = null`

Also, I don't see you are using that parameter in your query and so best is drop it;

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS userdb.new_test;
CREATE PROCEDURE userdb.new_test 
BEGIN   
  select * FROM message 
END;
```

Comment: just like the problem explained in the "SO link" above I call using @Procedure(name="new_test") List<Message> findBySome(@Param("value") String value); and its a test procedure which i want to extend to generate Dynamic queries, so I'll be using a lot more of IN params.

Comment: I tried your suggetion, yet getting the same error. could you please tell me if there's something I'm missing.