# JPA called stored procedure selecting data from 2 db

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am using mySql and jee application using jpa and hibernate

I have a stored procedure that deletes data from table in db1 then selects data from table from db2 and inserts them in table from db1

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `update_data`(myId int(11))
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM db1.tbl1
    WHERE db1.tbl1.id = myId;

    INSERT INTO
    db1.tbl1
    SELECT * FROM
    db2.tbl1
    WHERE db2.tbl1.id = myId;
END
```

When calling in sql it succeeds
When calling from jpa it returns exception

```
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-17) ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
ERROR [stderr] (default task-17) org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
```

JAVA code:

```
@PersistenceContext(name = "db2", unitName = "db2")
EntityManager em;

org.hibernate.Session session = (org.hibernate.Session) em.getDelegate();

        Transaction tx = null;
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            Query query = session
                    .createSQLQuery("CALL update_teachers(:sesId)")
                    .addEntity(Teacher.class).setParameter("sesId", sesId);
            query.list();
            session.flush();
            session.clear();

            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        session.close();
        }
```

The problem seems that there is selection from 2 different databases where em can't handle this operation
How can i perform this task

Note : I also tried [native named query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381394/hibernate-jpa-stored-procedure-call?rq=1)
and i tried [@NamedStoredProcedureQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578089/how-to-select-entities-by-calling-a-strored-procedure-with-spring-data?rq=1)
All gave the same exception

Comment: What is the value od `sesId` parameter when you call the procedure?And what MySQL version are you using? I found two MySQL bugs reported for this that could be related if you use the affected version: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15500 and http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25009

Answer (score 2):

You seem to execute the stored procedure and expect a result set in return:

```
query.list();
```

This doesn't seem correct to me, you won't be getting any records. Try calling it as if you want to run update or delete:

```
query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: The problem is that only returning an exception where in case the stored procedure is succeeding with no errors
I checked db and that what i found

Answer (score 0):

As Sva.Mu already wrote, the stored procedure call throws an exception because the entity manager expect a result from the call, if you use

```
query.list();
```

You can see it in this part of the error message

```
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-17) ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
```

The call should work, if you instead use

```
query.executeUpdate()
```

In that case, the entity manager will not expect any result from the stored procedure call.

This is the same, if you use a @NamedStoredProcedureQuery or the more dynamic StoredProcedureQuery. You can read more about it on my here: [@NamedStoredProcedureQuery](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/call-stored-procedures-jpa/) and [StoredProcedureQuery](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/call-stored-procedures-jpa-part-2/)